# Индекс находился вне границ массива C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Начал проходить курс по C# и дали задание на вычисление минимального значения в двухмерном массиве используя циклы

```
        int[,] x =
        {
            {20, 34, 2},
            {9, 12, 18},
            {3, 4, 5}
        };

        int min = x[0, 0];

        for (int a = 0; a < x.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < x.Length; b++)
            {
                if(x[a, b] < min)
                {
                    min = x[a, b];
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Минимальное значение: " +min);

        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
}
```

}

Саму ошибку выводит в

```
if(x[a, b] < min)
```

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

x.Length указывает на полную длину многомерного массива суммарно, то есть в вашем случае будет равно 9.

Поправьте код следующим образом:

```
int[,] x =
   {
        {20, 34, 2},
        {9, 12, 18},
        {3, 4, 5}
    };

int min = x[0, 0];

Console.WriteLine(x.Length);

for (int a = 0; a < x.GetLength(0); a++) // длина первго измерения
{
    for (int b = 0; b < x.GetLength(1); b++) // длина второго измерения
    {
        if (x[a, b] < min)
        {
            min = x[a, b];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Если помогло, галочка слева от ответа